# can any one help me with using IdentityServer3 to use MVCViewService with Aspidentity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, autofac, identityserver3

I am using IdentityServer3 samples to make a MVCView Service to work with asp.net identity. The samples work individually (i.e. plain idserver using asp.net identity Or MVC View Service showing custom login/logout pages).

However, when I try to combine both I get  below error

```
Unhandled exception accessing: /core/connect/authorize
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: A delegate registered to create instances of 'System.Object' returned null.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.AutofacDependencyResolver.Resolve[T](String name) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Services\Default\AutofacDependencyResolver.cs:line 36
   at MvcViewServiceSample.Startup.<>c.<Configuration>b__0_2(IDependencyResolver resolver) in D:\users\gbrapur\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\IdentityServer3.Samples-old\source\MVC ViewService\MvcViewServiceSample\Startup.cs:line 59
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting.AutofacConfig.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<Register>b__17(IComponentContext ctx) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\AutoFacConfig.cs:line 317
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10`1.<Register>b__f(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Registration.ExternalRegistrySource.<>c__DisplayClass8.<RegistrationsFor>b__3(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Internal\AntiXssLibrary\UnicodeCharacterEncoder.cs:line 0
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Extensions.InternalOwinExtensions.ResolveDependency(IOwinContext context, Type type) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Extensions\InternalOwinExtensions.cs:line 78
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Extensions.InternalOwinExtensions.ResolveDependency[T](IOwinContext context) in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Extensions\InternalOwinExtensions.cs:line 70
   at IdentityServer3.Core.Results.AuthorizeFormPostResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Results\AuthorizeFormPostResult.cs:line 61
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ballen\github\identity\IdSrv3\IdentityServer3\source\Core\Configuration\Hosting\NoCacheAttribute.cs:line 0
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : 09/21/2017 09:49:09 +01:00 [Error] ()
```

my configuration for Idserver is as listed below -

```
appBuilder.Map("/core", core =>
            {
                var idSvrFactory = Factory.Configure();

                // These registrations are also needed since these are dealt with using non-standard construction
                idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpContext>(resolver => HttpContext.Current));
                idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpContextBase>(resolver => new HttpContextWrapper(resolver.Resolve<HttpContext>())));
                idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpRequestBase>(resolver => resolver.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Request));
                idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpResponseBase>(resolver => resolver.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Response));
                idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpServerUtilityBase>(resolver => resolver.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Server));
                idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpSessionStateBase>(resolver => resolver.Resolve<HttpContextBase>().Session));

                idSvrFactory.ConfigureEPMUserService("AspId_CustomPK");
                idSvrFactory.ViewService = new Registration<IViewService, MvcViewService<LogonWorkflowController>>();

                var options = new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "IdentityServer3 - UserService-AspNetIdentity",
                    SigningCertificate = Certificate.Get(),
                    Factory = idSvrFactory,
                    AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders
                    }
                };

                core.UseIdentityServer(options);
            });
```

Error is thrown at this line

```
 idSvrFactory.Register(new Registration<HttpContextBase>(resolver => new HttpContextWrapper(resolver.Resolve<HttpContext>())));
```

Note that i'm not using autofac or any other DI

Comment: Hi, I have same problem and I haven't solved it. Did you solve the problem? Cheers

Comment: Sadly, I couldn't find any solution. The alternate was to  manually modify the chtml files (non mvc view) for login, logoff etc

Comment: Oh really? I cannot do that I need to MVC pattern.